# Search Column after LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql

Currently I have two tables.

Customers:

| id | name | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | adam | 1 |
| 2 | bob | 1 |
| 3 | cain | 2 |

Orders:

| customer_id | item |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | apple |
| 1 | banana |
| 1 | bonbon |
| 2 | carrot |
| 3 | egg |

I'm trying to do an INNER JOIN first then use the resulting table to query against.

So a user can type in a partial name or partial item and get all the names and items.
For example if a user type in "b" it would kick back:

| customer_id | name | status | items |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | adam | 1 | apple/banana/bonbon |
| 2 | bob | 1 | carrot |

What I am currently doing is:

```
SELECT * FROM(
                SELECT customers.* , GROUP_CONCAT(orders.item SEPARATOR '|') as items
                FROM customers 
                LEFT JOIN orders
                ON customers.id = orders.customer_id 
                group by customers.id 
            ) as t
            WHERE t.status = 1 AND ( t.name LIKE "%b%" OR t.items LIKE "%b%")
```

Which does work, but it is incredibly slow (+2 seconds).
The strange part though is if I run the queries individually the subquery executes in .0004 seconds and the outer query executes in .006 seconds.
But for some reason combining them increases the wait time a lot.

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `customers` (
  `id` int(6),
  `name` varchar(255) ,
  `status` int(6),
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`name`,`status`)
);
INSERT INTO `customers` (`id`, `name` , `status`) VALUES
  ('1',  'Adam' , 1),
  ('2', 'bob' , 1),
  ('3', 'cain' , 2);
  
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `orders` (
  `customer_id` int(6),
  `item` varchar(255) ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`customer_id`,`item`)
);
INSERT INTO `orders` (`customer_id`, `item`) VALUES
  ('1',  'apple'),
  ('1',  'banana'),
  ('1',  'bonbon'),
  ('2',  'carrot'),
  ('3', 'egg');
```

Comment: You use `GROUP_CONCAT(orders.item SEPARATOR '|')` without ORDER BY clause. Then you try to use `WHERE .. t.items LIKE "%b"` which is position-dependent. So you're just playing the lottery.

Comment: Please describe the task to be solved, not the way which you decide to use only...

Answer (score 1):

According to the query, you are trying to perform a full-text search on the fields `name` and `item`. I would suggest adding full-text indexes to them using ngram tokenisation as you are looking up by part of a word:

```
ALTER TABLE customers ADD FULLTEXT INDEX ft_idx_name (name) WITH PARSER ngram;
ALTER TABLE orders ADD FULLTEXT INDEX ft_idx_item (item) WITH PARSER ngram;
```

In this case, your query would look as follows:

```
SELECT
    customers.*, GROUP_CONCAT(orders.item SEPARATOR '|')
FROM
    customers
    LEFT JOIN orders on customers.id = orders.customer_id
WHERE
    orders.customer_id IS NOT NULL
    AND customers.status = 1
    AND (MATCH(customers.name) AGAINST('bo')
        OR MATCH(orders.item) AGAINST('bo'))
GROUP BY
    customers.id
```

If needed, you could modify `ngram_token_size` MySQL system variable as its value is 2 by default, which means two or more characters should be input to perform the search.

Another approach is to implement it by means of a dedicated search engine, e.g. Elasticsearch, when requirements evolve.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM(
        SELECT customers.* , GROUP_CONCAT(orders.item SEPARATOR '|') as items
        FROM customers 
        LEFT JOIN orders
        ON customers.id = orders.customer_id AND customers.name LIKE "%adam" AND orders.item LIKE "%b"
        group by customers.AI
```

It will be faster to filter the records when starting to left join

Comment: I've amended the OP to add some clarity to the expected result. While this solution is quicker, it doesn't get the same result as expected.